# Run Perl script in SunOS machine

Tags: perl

We have a SunOS machine where we run our daily jobs, on failures we usually login into the machine (using Putty) and run a perl script that take an input parameter to start the failed jobs. Similarly if we need to stop a job we follow the same process and run another script.
I would like to formulate a single script outside of the remote machine which would follow the process of logging in , navigating to the directory where the script is and running the script.
Just looking for ideas as to see how i can implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking into Net::OpenSSH (https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH).  I've used this with great success to connect to remote machines, execute commands, and capture their output. Also, connection creation can be greatly simplified if you set up passwordless authentication to your remote machines.  Then you can test your commands from the command line (and chain commands together):

```
ssh host 'cd dir1/dir2 && run_script'
```

The implementation in the controlling script would be to the tune of:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($my_host);
my ($out, $err) = $ssh->capture2($my_command);
```